# PrimeFaces treeTable commandButton not invoked

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I know this question has been asked before, but all answeres did not work or are for a VERY old version of Primefaces.

I hava a simple `<p:treeTable` with a commandButtion in a `<p:column` but the action is only executed for the root elements in the tree.

```
<p:treeTable var="ou" 
    value="#{oumanagement.ouTree}" 
    class="userList" 
    id="outable"
    selectionMode="single">

    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="List of Organisational Units" />
    </f:facet>

    <p:column headerText="Organisational Unit" >
        <h:outputText value="#{ou.name}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <p:commandButton action="#{oumanagement.remove(ou.id)}" icon="fa fa-trash-o" update=":ouform:outable :ouform:msgs" transient="true">
           <p:confirm header="Are You Sure" message="Are you sure?" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
        </p:commandButton>
     </p:column>
     <p:column>
         <p:commandButton action="#{oumanagement.viewDetails(ou.id)}" icon="fa fa-sliders" transient="true"  ajax="false"/>
      </p:column>
</p:treeTable>
```

The action is very simple:

```
public String viewDetails(int id) {
    activeOU = ouService.find(id);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().put("ou", activeOU);
    return "/pages/secure/organisationManagement/details";
}
```

I'm using Primefaces version 5.1

Thanks for any hints and help

---

Updated to Primefaces 5.2 still same problem

Comment: Why did you set `transient` associated with those `<p:commandButton>`s to `true`?

Comment: Ok at this point im not sure why it was in there. Removbed it but it did not solve the problem. Thanks for pointing it out though.

Comment: can you add `process="@this"` to your command buttons and try again?

Comment: Did not make any difference